# Dynamic Memory C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, new-operator

I have a trouble while I delete memory allocated with the next code:

```
int main(){
    char **cities;

    cities = new char*[MAX_CITIES];
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CITIES; i += 1){
        cities[i] = new char[MAX_CITY_LENGTH];
        cities[i] = "CITY"; //Its only a test value
    }
    cout << "Memory allocated successfully" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CITIES; i += 1){
        cout << cities[i] << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CITIES; i += 1){
        delete[] cities[i];
    }
    delete[] cities;
    cout << "Memory freed successfully" << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: what sort of problem are you seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
cities[i] = "CITY"; //Its only a test value
```

This does *not* copy `CITY` into the memory you must allocated. Instead, it overwrites the pointer to the memory you just allocated with a pointer to the string literal "CITY".

When you try to delete that, problems arise because it's not memory that was allocated with `new`. Since you overwrote the pointer to the memory you allocated, it just gets leaked.

To make it work, replace `cities[i] = "CITY";` with `strcpy(cities[i], "CITY");` so you copy the characters into the memory you allocated.

Having said that, use `std::vector<std::string>` if you have any choice in the matter at all.

Comment: Thanks, now if I want to separate the code in functions that do the allocating and freeing of memory I have an error. The fist function haves the structure void loadCities(char **cities) and the second function haves the structure void deleteCities(char **cities)

Comment: @user2813556: Think hard about the last sentence of the answer. If you can't use the standard types, it's going to be easier to create minimal versions of your own, then use them, than to handle all this directly.